# Display a label inside a chart point in a BubbleSerie

Tags: c#, livecharts

How do I display a label inside a chart point using a BubbleSeries (or anyother series) ?

Answer (score 2):

This should work on any series in LiveCharts:

- to display a label on a chart point, set the DataLabels=true on the series
- to customize the displayed label, use the LabelPoint property on the series

Example (Notice BubbleSeries will change to ScatterSeries in next version of the library):

```
var mySeries = new ScatterSeries
{
    Values = new ChartValues<ScatterPoint> { new ScatterPoint(3,4,80) },
    DataLabels = true,
    LabelPoint = point => point.X + "," + point.Y + "," + point.Weight
};
```

Will display

[image]